# Remove 2 way switches from outlet to remain always hot

Tags: wiring

Currently I have an outlet that is able to be turned on and off by 2 separate switches. I would like to remove the switches and always keep the outlet on.

To complete this task would I just wire nut the wires together that are attached to the switches?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: You could get two shabbos light switch covers and cover the switches in the ON position. Easy and readily reversible. Lotsa different types. https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shabbat+light+switch+covers&hvadid=381085218361&hvdev=t&hvlocphy=9026945&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=9326130028301786600&hvtargid=kwd-415610387400&hydadcr=15284_9741750&tag=googhydr-20&ref=pd_sl_3bfumkr9pp_e

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is a bit more complicated in your situation. If it was only one switch, yes you could just wire nut together the two wires and you'd be done (except switched light note, see below).

However, you have 2 switches. Which means each has **three** wires on it - one common and two travelers. If you wire nut all three wires together then it will work but not be legal as you will then be paralleling, which is only allowed in some very specific situations with very large wires.

If you open up the switches, you should find that each has one wire on one color screw and two wires on another color screw - e.g., one black screw, two brass screws. The two wires that are on the same color screws are *travelers*. Connect *one* traveler to the common wire. Connect the *same* traveler to the common wire on the other switch. If you have cables (black/white, black/red/white) then the travelers will be two different colors and this is easy. But if you have individual wires in conduit then the travelers may be the same color wire and then you have to figure out which one is which so that the two switch bypass wire nuts are connecting to the same traveler.

**Switched Light**

Most rooms are supposed to have a switched light. This is a code requirement so that people can walk into a room and have a standardized way to turn on the light. Important for guests. Extremely important for first responders (police, fire, emergency medical).

That can be accomplished with a switch controlling a wall or ceiling light or by a switch controlling a receptacle with a lamp plugged into the receptacle. Often, because builders are cheap, kitchens and bathrooms will have switched light fixtures and bedrooms, living rooms, etc. will have switched receptacles as you have described here. If you bypass the switches then either the switches will have no effect (confusing to people walking into the room) or you will remove the switches and then people will have no idea how to turn on the lights.

So think twice before doing this. The proper way to do this is to make the receptacle always hot but *at the same time* wire up a wall or ceiling light fixture to the switches.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but you would loose serviceability for the light, and need to find and **clearly mark** the circuit breaker for it to be able to service it. –

Since the light is always on, the **switched light requirement** described by manassehkatz is not longer valid. –

To avoid the code problem on running parallel wires, just use one and blank off the other –

Back to your question: You say those are switched outlets (not lights), then you can simply wire them together.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact wondering why you have lengthy paragraph about 'Switched Light`

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact so why is it that you can talk about switched light, but have problem if I talk about it

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact correct, just wondering why did you then explain the code and rules about light switch